# A Modern Knight

Tags: technology, medieval, military, armors, melee

I am an eccentric billionaire with a strong preference for all things medieval. However, my company happens to produce state-of-the-art modern military technology. Fascinated by stories portraying heavily armed spacefarers or time travellers fighting against medieval knights, I have decided to ask: **"Why not combine both worlds?"**

A knight by definition is an armored and heavily armed warrior who fights on horseback and on his feet with melee weapons.

Therefore, I am tasking you with the development of armor, equipment and weapons needed for a **modern knight**.

The following conditions must be fulfilled:

- Modern to near future technology but no significant mechanic encachement/exoskeleton elements. This means that kevlar armor or a modern helmet is allowed, but that an adult, fit man (you can assume a trained special forces soldier or sportsman) should be able to put on the equipment with a little bit of help from an assistant and carry and use the weapons using his own strength. Of course, electronic augmentations such as a wrist display that reports damage to the armor is permitted.
- The knight must fight using only melee weapons.
- The knight must be able to fight both on horseback and by foot, depending on situation.
- The usual setup of sword for attack and shield for protection is preferred.
- After sufficient training, the knight who receives the equipment should be able to duel another similarily armed knight or robot.
- Bonus: The knight should be able to perform classic horseback lance duels.

Comment: Done - titanium pads with non-newtonian fluid. I wil cash my check on the way out thank you very much.

Comment: What's the point? Why not use medieval weapons? Also there are plenty of modern knights (and dames) around , they are created in the annual Honours Lists.

Comment: "should be able to duel" - someone totally untrained could turn up in a tracksuit with a broomhandle and participate in a duel, albeit with poor chances of success.  Is there an "improved ability to win over an equally-trained but classically equipped opponent" requirement missing from the question?

Comment: Phone call from gritty billionaire playboy Bruce Wayne on line 1 for you....

Comment: This is not about world-building. It is about a story line. Also, we don't do "tasks" here, we help people of our own free will. (To quote a phrase) Please take a look at the [tour] and [help] to remind yourself how not waste our time. We're here to help you build the foundations of your world, not satisfy your fantasies or forward your story.

Comment: I'm with @elemtilas. We're willing to help you develop world rules and systems that would justify the existence of this anachronism, but the anachronism itself is (from a worldbuilding POV) aesthetic and therefore story-dependent. I'd also point out that the classic "knight" that can fight both on horseback and on foot is something of a fantasy contrivance. Getting on and off a horse in armor is non-trivial. Getting up from the prone position is non-trivial. So there were different armor designs for the two functions. (Besides, take a modern soldier and hand him a saber + lance. job done.)

Comment: Should also be noted that knight does not mean all that rubbish about heavily armored and melee weapons and all that. Knight originally meant a servant or attendant, but eventually took on a military character coming to mean a military follower of a king. By the time we get all romantic about knights, it has become much more a matter of courtesy, a high honour & dignity bestowed by the monarch such that a knight is now a rank of minor nobility.

Answer (score 2):

> Modern to near future technology but no significant mechanic
> encachement/exoskeleton elements. This means that kevlar armor or a
> modern helmet is allowed, but that an adult, fit man (you can assume a
> trained special forces soldier or sportsman) should be able to put on
> the equipment with a little bit of help from an assistant and carry
> and use the weapons using his own strength. Of course, electronic
> augmentations such as a wrist display that reports damage to the armor
> is permitted.

1. You can use modern metalurgy for more durable and light alloys for armor and weapons
2. You can use modern technology and engineering to maximize effeciency a personalization of armor for knight.
3. If you allowed hypermodern weapon like nanoblade (sword with molecule thin blade) i can imagine knight more focused on mobility with lighter armor if that sword can cut throught armor. But this weapon would make heavy knight obsolete.
4. Support - i can imagine that knight armor can be rigged with electronic, from simple radio, to hi-tech stuff you can see in cyberpunk like damage sensor, infra/night vision. face recognition, friend or foe system.

Optional -
Some basic pasive exoskeleton function could be used too, not powered just saving some stamina for soldier. Some time ago i have seen testing at FORD where mechanic completing car are forced to have hands raised above neck more than 50% of time. it will support their arms. At the end of his shift he wasnt totaly spend.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvXAooTRi1U

> The knight must fight using only melee weapons.

- Swords, hammers, … daggers. Its about training and doctrine.

> The knight must be able to fight both on horseback and by foot,
> depending on situation.

- Same as before its about training and your equipment

> The usual setup of sword for attack and shield for protection is
> preferred.

- if you want fight of knight in heavy armor (honor fight 1v1 or gladiator type) sword and shield is not much viable
- in history when two fullplate knight fighted they holded their sword by blade and atacked by other end of sword. Kinda like when using mace. You try to knock him down and then use your weight se he can get up while you are trying stab him with thin dagger in his weakpoint

Mordhau technique in the year 1459.
https://www.thevintagenews.com/2019/02/17/mordhau/

The German word Mordhau translates roughly as “murder stroke” or “murder strike”. It represents a particular move in German medieval swordsmanship where the fighter holds the blade of his sword with both hands and essentially uses the weapon more like a mace or war hammer to hit his opponent.

> After sufficient training, the knight who receives the equipment
> should be able to duel another similarily armed knight or robot.

-honor duels

> Bonus: The knight should be able to perform classic horseback lance
> duels.

-there would be special armor for horseriding lance duels

Extra

I would recomend to look up youtube channel Metatron and shadiversity

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIjGKyrdT4Gja0VLO40RlOw

https://www.youtube.com/user/shadmbrooks

It all depend what you want, just duels, team duels, honor fight.
Should that knight fight against modern soldier?

Also there can be many auguments on soldier side, different body enhacments. you can be insipered by shadowrun and clasical cyberpunk
Also dont forget combat drugs